# Example of Conditional Expectation in Markov Chain

Tags: self-study, markov-process, conditional-expectation

My question is from the book *Introduction to Probability Models*, 10th edition, by Sheldon Ross.

Here is a example in the book. 
Consider a Markov chain with states $0, 1,\cdots , n$ having
$P_{0,1} = 1, P_{i,i+1} = p, P_{i,i−1} = q = 1 − p, 1 \leq i < n$.

and suppose that we are interested in studying the time that it takes for the chain to go from state $0$ to state $n$.

One of the approaches the author uses in the book is to construct a Markov Chain. The method is as following:

let $N_i$ denote the number of additional transitions that it takes the chain when it first enters state $i$ until it enters state $i + 1$. By the Markovian property, it follows that these random variables $N_i, i = 0, . . . , n − 1$ are independent. Also, we can express $N_{0,n}$, the
number of transitions that it takes the chain to go from state $0$ to state $n$, as
$$ N_{0,n} = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}N_i$$
Letting $\mu_i = E[N_i]$ we obtain, upon conditioning on the next transition after the
chain enters state $i$, that for $i = 1, . . . , n − 1$

$$\mu_i = 1 + E[\text{number of additional transitions to reach } i + 1|\text{chain to } i − 1]q$$.

My question is why the author uses 1 instead of $p$ in the last equation.

To me, it sounds more reasonable that
$$\begin{align} \mu_i &= E[\text{number of additional transitions to reach } i + 1 \text{ from } i|\text{chain to } i + 1]p \\&  \quad+ E[\text{number of additional transitions to reach } i + 1\text{ from } i|\text{chain to } i − 1]q \\ &= p + E[\text{number of additional transitions to reach } i + 1|\text{chain to } i − 1]q \end{align}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full problem statement can be found from Google books at [Section 4.5.3 of Sheldon M. Ross "Introduction to Probability Models"](https://books.google.com/books?id=0yDAZf1TfJEC&pg=PA237&lpg=PA237&dq=denote%20the%20number%20of%20additional%20transitions%20that%20it%20takes&source=bl&ots=dKL7ZWKjws&sig=ruR4SFxSuKCKPbnOgNhEbDwlucc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMrIDAt8vMAhXiKMAKHcsCCosQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=denote%20the%20number%20of%20additional%20transitions%20that%20it%20takes&f=false).

There is always at least one additional transition to get from state $i$ to state $i+1$.  That is the "1" which you think should be a $p$. In reality, there is also a "missing" term, which does not appear, because it comes out to $0$; that is the term in which the $p$ actually appears.

So the "unabridged" version of the equation in the book is:

$$\mu_i = 1 + E[\text{number of additional transitions to reach } i+1|\text{chain to }i+1] p + E[\text{number of additional transitions to reach }i+1|\text{chain to }i-1] q$$

Then note that $E[\text{number of additional transitions to reach } i+1|\text{chain to }i+1] = 0$

It may help your interpretation to think of $E[\text{number of additional transitions to reach } i+1|\text{chain to }i+1]$ as meaning $E[\text{number of additional transitions to reach } i+1|\text{chain IS IN }i+1]$, which you can clearly see as being $0$.

Note that instead of writing the equation as I did, it could be written with the $1$ instead included in each of the other two terms, which perhaps you might find to be more natural, as follows:

$$\mu_i = (1 + E[\text{number of additional transitions to reach } i+1|\text{chain to }i+1]) p + (1 + E[\text{number of additional transitions to reach }i+1|\text{chain to }i-1]) q$$ and of course this reduces to the previous equation given that $p + q = 1$.

Comment: I forgot to count the move from $i$ to the next state previously. Many thanks.  @Mark L. Stone.